Most resilient RDMS DB to unexpected power losses?
If we need to choose a RDMS option to run, not in a server environment, but somewhere (not even a building) where power can go off at any moment a few times a day, what options would be the best? Also if that system would run on a CoW FS like ZFS or BTRFS, would that change anything?
The hardware will be running unattended, so my biggest priority is returning to a safe working state after sudden power loss without admin intervention. In the other hand a few seconds or even minutes of data loss before the power loss would be no problem in this application.
Of course the best solution would be to use a UPS, but that's not always possible. The reasons for UPS being a problem can be space, weight, costs, regulations...

It's usually pointless to ask for close vote reasons in a comment. The voters are often long gone. Your best bet is to make your question as good as possible, by improving it. Leaving information in comments doesn't have the same effect. Some will still think your question is too broad, or prone to being answered with personal OS/DBMS preferences rather than specific (database) domain expertise.

Any modern DBMS is resilient against this kind of failure, but not resilient enough to guarantee it'll come up without the need for manual intervention every single time.
Invest in a battery backup.
If there were one that's "the best", all of them would therefore use the same approach and would also be "the best". Since all of them use more or less the same mechanism (write-ahead logging), you can think of it as "the best", or that "the best" doesn't exist.

what's keeping them from not being able to "come up without the need for manual intervention every single time"?

It's one of those pesky low probability events, like turning power off in the middle of a multi-block flush, or the CPU staying on a tiny bit longer than the disk, or the associated current surge triggering a few gates or magnetising a few domains here and there, or...

Thanks for taking the time to answer. Even if we fully prioritize rebooting into a safe & working sate automatically over last written data retention, best we can do is to randomly pick one? Also, I would have thought that a CoW FS would have changed things at least a little bit, as it should eliminate the possibility to half written DB files.

@Héctor, I'm not even following why CoW filesystems are involved in your thinking? Mainstream DB engines work by default on the basis that no data is lost from a mere power outage.

Corruption risk I was guessing, but I didn't know, that's why I was asking. Now I do and that's nice. So what's keeping them from not being able to "come up without the need for manual intervention every single time"?
